# Facebook Javascript SDK - How to tie with ASP.NET MVC Login?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 web application, and I would like to use Facebook to authenticate users.

My plan is to have users "Sign Up" with Facebook, and then login using it.

Now this is fine when a user comes to the site and logs in with the Facebook Login button I have setup, which goes through an /Account/FacebookLogin action. In that action I can grab the Auth Token and check it against an SQL database to then authenticate the user with all the extra fields/info I store about them in my database (It's a web based game so Character name etc)...

Now, if the user comes to my site and they are already logged into Facebook, they obviously don't go through that /Account/FacebookLogin action... I simply have access to the auth token through the

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            //alert("User is logged in");
        }
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //alert("User is not authorised");
        }
        else {
            //alert("User is not connected to Facebook");
        }

    });
```

My question is... What can I do in the "if connected" code to authorize my user, without sending them into an infinite loop? I tried redirecting them to the /Account/FacebookLogin action and passing in the auth token etc. But the getLoginStatus callback is called on every page... so they get stuck in an infinite loop..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has given you access to someone's Facebook identity. You might now want to create a user account for that identity. Once that user has an account then you then need to get the user to authenticate themselves with your application (you can use the Facebook identity to do this if you wish to tie yourself to Facebook). You can then authorize that user to undertake certain actions within your application.

In the context of MVC, you could quite simply issue them with a forms authentication token:

```
var username = response.authResponse.name; // <- check the syntax on this
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "AuthorizedUsersOnlyController");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that bit I have figured out. My question relates to what to do when users, who are already logged into Facebook, visit my site. I have resolved this by simply having it redirect them via Javascript to an authorized controller so they effectively "skip" my home page and immediately get moved to the authorized section of the site.